# While Loop doesn't parse/paste the strings correctly

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a .txt file with the following content:

```
"aaa@bbb.de"
```

Now, I want to paste these strings with the help of my while loop to the stdout, in such a way that echo should write `"text aaa@bbb.de text"`

```
while read line;
do 
    echo "text $line text"
done <./textfile.txt
```

But all I get is: `text"aaa@bbb.de"`

--> The whitespaces are missing and the `text` after `$line` as well.

If I change it as below

```
while read line;
do 
     echo "text\ $line text"
done <./textfile.txt
```

I get `text "aaa@bbb.de"`

--> After the first `text`, there is a whitespace but after `aaa@bbb.de`, there is no `text`.

Comment: By using the same string, `text` at each end of your `echo` statement you can't tell when you see the string `text` in the output if it's the string from before `$line` or the same string from after it. Given that, when you say `The whitespaces are missing and the text after $line as well.` you're misdiagnosing the problem - it's not the `text` **after** `$line` that's missing, it's the `text` before it that's missing as it's being overwritten by the `text` after it. Change `echo "text $line text"` to `echo "foo $line bar"` and it'll be much easier for you to see what's really happening.

Comment: General rule of thumb when writing debugging print statements - don't use the same string in multiple locations in those print statements or you won't be able to tell where that string came from when you see it in the output and so will be missing useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [using shell loops for text processing is considered bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/377345), I would recommend a different approach that uses dedicated text-processing tools. In particular, `awk` comes to mind:

```
awk '{printf "text %s text\n",$0}' textfile.txt
```

This will use Awk's builtin `printf` function (using the same formatting syntax as the well-known C function) to print the entire current line (represented by `$0`) enclosed by `text` on both ends.

**As for why your approach didn't work:** Since you confirmed that the text file was edited on a Windows-based machine, this means that the line endings are in a format the Linux doesn't correctly interpret. In that case, run the file through `dos2unix`, as in

```
dos2unix textfile.txt
```

The resulting file should be processed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing myself to `perl` so feel free to learn with me:

```
perl -ne ' s/\n|"//g ; print "\"text $_ text2\"\n" ' infile.txt
```

- read file line-by-line `-n`
- execute the inline script `-e`
- remove all newline and quotes from input line `s/\n|"//g`
- and print string in desired format
- `$_` is the variable for the input and its processed form, respectively